# HubPipelineModule.BuildRejoiningGroups method doesn't work with websockets

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, owin

I have written some code using signalR. The main idea is that we support several groups of users. Each group is identified with a token(some string value). This token is passed to the server from a client via a query string. Then all clients with the same token gets updates from server.
Here is a very simplified version of my code.

I use HubPipelineModule for supporting groups in signalR. Suppose that token is always passed from the client so we can take its value from the Referer header.

```
public class RejoingGroupPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    public override Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> BuildRejoiningGroups(
        Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> rejoiningGroups)
    {
        return (hb, r, l) =>
        {
            return new[] { GetTaskToken(r) };
        };
    }

    public static String GetGroupName(IRequest request)
    {
        var refererHeader = request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key == "Referer");
        var uriString = refererHeader.Value;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uriString))
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return "defaultToken";
    }
}
```

RejoinGroupPipelineModule is registered in Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new RejoingGroupPipelineModule());
    }
}
```

Then a Hub class updates Clients.

```
public class BaseHub : Hub
{
    public void Update()
    {
        context.Clients.Groups(new[]{"defaultToken"}).updateClient(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

The method BaseHub.Update is called repeatedly on timer. So all clients are refreshed with server time.
When signalR uses long polling everything is OK and clients are updated. But when signalR uses web sockets there is a problem:

1) A request with uri `http://localhost/signalr/CONNECT?transport=webSockets&...` is passed to the method BuildRejoiningGroups. Request does not contain a referer header so we cannot determine a right group.

2)Then a request with uri `http://localhost/signalr/START?transport=webSockets&...` is passed to the method. Now Referer header is presented in the request. We can take a token and return a right function. But clients are not updated. I suggest that rejoining groups are not actually updated.

I used the next workaround:

```
public override Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> BuildRejoiningGroups(
        Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> rejoiningGroups)
    {
        return (hb, r, l) =>
        {
            if (r.Headers.All(h => h.Key != "Referer"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new[] { GetTaskToken(r) };
        };
    }
```

Now clients are updated but "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null" is being throwning.

My questions are: Why last rejoining groups are not used? How to take a token from a query string correctly? How to avoid System.ArgumentNullException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why last rejoining groups are not used?

   SignalR is designed so that it can be used behind a load balancer. This means that different requests can potentially be sent to different servers for the same SignalR "connection". For this reason, SignalR tries to keep most state, like the groups the client has joined in the form of the `groupsToken`, on the client itself.
2. How to take a token from a query string correctly?

   SignalR already has it's own "groupsToken" to ensure clients are securely re-added to groups they have already joined as a result of a call to `Groups.Add` when they reconnect. Why are you not using SignalR's built-in group rejoining functionality? If you want to always add a connection to a default group based on on the presence of the Referer header, you can do this in `OnConnected`.

   ```
   public override Task OnConnected()
   {
       var refererHeader = Context.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key == "Referer");
       var uriString = refererHeader.Value;
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uriString))
       {
           Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, GetTaskToken(Context.Request));
       }

       return base.OnConnected();
   }
   ```

   Starting in SignalR 2.1.0, OnConnected is always called in response to the Ajax /start request, meaning that the Referer header should be accessible unlike with WebSocket requests.
3. How to avoid System.ArgumentNullException?

   Don't return null from the Func you return in `BuildRejoiningGroups`. Instead you should use the paremeter to get the groups that SignalR would normally rejoin the client to.

   ```
   public override Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> BuildRejoiningGroups(
       Func<HubDescriptor, IRequest, IList<string>, IList<string>> rejoiningGroups)
   {
       return (hb, r, l) =>
       {
           // Get the groups SignalR would rejoin the client to by default
           var groupsToRejoin = rejoiningGroups(hb, r, l);

           // I would ensure that groupsToRejoin doesn't already contain the group
           // GetTaskToken would add, because SignalR will rejoin the group automatically
           // if the client has already be added to the group.
           if (r.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == "Referer"))
           {
               groupsToRejoin.Add(GetTaskToken(r));
           }

           return groupsToRejoin;
       };
   }
   ```

P.S. The "Referer" header, as you noted, isn't sent with WebSocket requests. However, the similar "Origin" header is sent.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works great! I only want to add that I've used a "defaultToken" in the example for the sake of simplicity. Actually the token is like an identifier of a real process shown to a user. Also I should have read http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups more attentively.